# scale database on Openshift

Tags: database, openshift, scale

Is it possible to scale horizontally a database on Openshift?

For example mongoDB, can you have replicas if you have a multi gear MongoDB application in Openshift?

What about the relational databases? Is it possible to have a Galera cluster on Openshift for example?

Answer (score 2):

You can use external services in OpenShift Marketplace - Check [uservoice answer here](https://openshift.uservoice.com/forums/258655-ideas/suggestions/6291446-make-databases-scalable).

> Check out the DBaaS solutions available in the OpenShift Marketplace:
>
> 1. ClearDB (MySQL): https://developers.openshift.com/en/marketplace-cleardb-mysql-database.html
> 2. ElephantSQL (PostgreSQL): https://developers.openshift.com/en/marketplace-elephantsql.html
> 3. MongoLab (MongoDB): https://developers.openshift.com/en/marketplace-mongolab.html
> 4. Redis Cloud (Redis): https://developers.openshift.com/en/marketplace-redis-cloud.html

Comment: Uservoice link is down.